# Having trouble with operating text file with special charcters in .bat program

Tags: batch-file, encryption, special-characters

Question reformatted, now that reason for error has been found.

**Background info:**
So I am fairly new to .bat so any general advice on my code would be great. I am running a simple program on a flash drive that will encrypt the contents of another file on my flash drive. These files could contain any keyboard characters, so I need to be able to handle all of them.

**The error:**
It appears that even though I am using delayedExpansinon my program still cannot handle poison characters. My program no loops through many lines (thanks to michael_heath) however the following error log shows a new error. It appears that " are still a problem. Also in testing I discovered that it does not work with % or ! in abet and cipher1.

NOTE to fix this I attempted to add enabledealyedexpansion to the entire encrypt/dycrpt functionality. This did eliminate my error involving " but my code does not handle % and ! anymore.

**The program**

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd BatchMenu/BatchLibs
set "command=%3"
set "drivePath=%2"
set "fileName=%1"

set "abet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@# $%^&*()_-+={[}]/?<,>.\|~`':; 0123456789"
set "cipher1=;~`8p#j4*&9z\6w+}.{a@%^e?[@0u2< r|5)o!(xk_-[cf'1b3g7h=m>,qil/sntdvy:"
if "%command%" == "d" goto dycrypt
goto encrypt

:encrypt
(
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%drivePath%%fileName%.txt") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=%%~A"
        call :encipher
        endlocal
    )
) 3> "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt"

if exist "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" ren "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" "%fileName%.bak"
ren "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt" "%fileName%.txt"
del "%drivePath%%fileName%.bak"
goto :eof

:dycrypt
(
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%drivePath%%fileName%.txt") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=%%~A"
        call :decipher
        endlocal
    )
) 3> "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt"

if exist "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" ren "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" "%fileName%.bak"
ren "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt" "%fileName%.txt"
del "%drivePath%%fileName%.bak"
goto :eof

:decipher
set "morf=%abet%"
set "from=%cipher1%"
goto trans

:encipher
set "from=%abet%"
set "morf=%cipher1%"

:trans
set "enil="

:transl
set "$1=%from%"
set "$2=%morf%"

:transc
if /i "!line:~0,1!" == "!$1:~0,1!" (
set "enil=%enil%%$2:~0,1%"
goto transnc
)
set "$1=%$1:~1%"
set "$2=%$2:~1%"

IF defined $2 goto transc
:: No translation - keep
set "enil=%enil%%line:~0,1%"

:transnc
set "line=!line:~1!"
if defined line goto transl

if defined enil >&3 echo !enil!
goto :eof
```

**Error Log**

```
E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$1=rstuvwxyz@# $; 0123456789" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$2=.{a@" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>IF defined $2 goto transc 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>if /I "|" == "r" (
set "enil=1|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|13101368703482566|805152|805152|1|0|0|13101368703615493|1|4aa+{://`w@.{p{.{`4wwz.p8@/wp~;++{/~z;`9~w;.8/pxp`@ap/8*{+z;y*68*v*8@;z`w6ap6a?\w8p=v*pw&`w6ap6a_*8=_1553882_1&`w@.{p_*8=_75015_1||."  
 goto transnc 
) 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$1=stuvwxyz@# $; 0123456789" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$2={a@" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>IF defined $2 goto transc 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>if /I "|" == "s" (
set "enil=1|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|13101368703482566|805152|805152|1|0|0|13101368703615493|1|4aa+{://`w@.{p{.{`4wwz.p8@/wp~;++{/~z;`9~w;.8/pxp`@ap/8*{+z;y*68*v*8@;z`w6ap6a?\w8p=v*pw&`w6ap6a_*8=_1553882_1&`w@.{p_*8=_75015_1||{"  
 goto transnc 
) 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$1=tuvwxyz@# $; 0123456789" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$2=a@" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>IF defined $2 goto transc 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>if /I "|" == "t" (
set "enil=1|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|13101368703482566|805152|805152|1|0|0|13101368703615493|1|4aa+{://`w@.{p{.{`4wwz.p8@/wp~;++{/~z;`9~w;.8/pxp`@ap/8*{+z;y*68*v*8@;z`w6ap6a?\w8p=v*pw&`w6ap6a_*8=_1553882_1&`w@.{p_*8=_75015_1||a"  
 goto transnc 
) 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$1=uvwxyz@# $; 0123456789" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$2=@" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>IF defined $2 goto transc 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>if /I "|" == "u" (
set "enil=1|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|13101368703482566|805152|805152|1|0|0|13101368703615493|1|4aa+{://`w@.{p{.{`4wwz.p8@/wp~;++{/~z;`9~w;.8/pxp`@ap/8*{+z;y*68*v*8@;z`w6ap6a?\w8p=v*pw&`w6ap6a_*8=_1553882_1&`w@.{p_*8=_75015_1||@"  
 goto transnc 
) 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$1=vwxyz@# $; 0123456789" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$2=" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>IF defined $2 goto transc 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "enil=1|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|`:\@{p.{\;w;.8zww\8ww6zw;8{\*6a.w aw .4paw.*` ;68 pa4w{.++ax|13101368703482566|805152|805152|1|0|0|13101368703615493|1|4aa+{://`w@.{p{.{`4wwz.p8@/wp~;++{/~z;`9~w;.8/pxp`@ap/8*{+z;y*68*v*8@;z`w6ap6a?\w8p=v*pw&`w6ap6a_*8=_1553882_1&`w@.{p_*8=_75015_1|||" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "line="797816-901A5E25AE3F84AAC67979FF01AA681E"|Mon, 29 Feb 2016 11:54:54 GMT|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>if defined line goto transl 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$1=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@# $; 0123456789" 

E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>set "$2=;~`8p#j4*&9z\6w+}.{a@" 
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
E:\BatchMenu\BatchLibs>if /i """ == "a" (

*NOTE to fix this I attempted to add enabledealyedexpansion to the entire encrypt/dycrpt functionality. This did eliminate this error but my code does not handle % and ! anymore.
```

Comment: So what line generates the error message? Please read [Debugging batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) and [edit] your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill sorry about that, I actually already knew what line it happens on...sort of. When I run it (including with your logFile approach which is helpful so thank you) it shows the for loop then immediately afterward it shows my error.

Comment: I suspect some poison characters in your string(s). Please change your `set` commands to the following syntax: `set "var=value"` (note the position of the spaces) and try again. If that doesn't help, please add `echo "%%a"` as first line  inside the `for` loop and tell us what it says.

Comment: @Stephan thank you for your help. While it does seem to fix my https and url problem. There is a new error in the same place that seems to be the same problem. Now it errors on seeing 'o2.'. Also the echo "%%a" does not seem to print new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd Batch/BatchLibrariesLocation

set "command=%~3"
set "drivePath=%~2"
set "fileName=%~1"

set "abet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@# $%%^&*()_-+={[}]/?<,>.\|~`':; 0123456789"
set "cipher1=;~`8p#j4*&9z\6w+}.{a@%%^e?[@0u2< r|5)o!(xk_-[cf'1b3g7h=m>,qil/sntdvy:"

if "%command%" == "d" goto dycrypt
goto encrypt

:encrypt
(
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%drivePath%%fileName%.txt") do (
        set "line=%%A"
        call :encipher
    )
) 3> "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt"

if exist "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" ren "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" "%fileName%.bak"
ren "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt" "%fileName%.txt"
goto :eof

:dycrypt
(
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%drivePath%%fileName%.txt") do (
        set "line=%%A"
        call :decipher
    )
) 3> "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt"

if exist "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" ren "%drivePath%%fileName%.txt" "%fileName%.bak2"
ren "%drivePath%%fileName%temp.txt" "%fileName%.txt"
goto :eof

:decipher
set "morf=!abet!"
set "from=!cipher1!"
goto trans

:encipher
set "from=!abet!"
set "morf=!cipher1!"

:trans
set "enil="

:transl
set "$1=!from!"
set "$2=!morf!"

:transc
if /i "!line:~0,1!" == "!$1:~0,1!" set "enil=!enil!!$2:~0,1!"& goto transnc
set "$1=!$1:~1!"
set "$2=!$2:~1!"

IF defined $2 goto transc
:: No translation - keep
set "enil=!enil!!line:~0,1!"

:transnc
set "line=!line:~1!"
if defined line goto transl
if not defined enil goto :eof
>&3 echo !enil!
goto :eof
```

Double quoted variables and strings as needed.

Option `usebackq` with `for` loops so can double quote paths.

Output echoed to file from the `for` loops now using
stream 3 so that `echo on` can be used and any echo
using stream 1 will not be redirected to file.
`3>` used to redirect stream 3 to file and `>&3` on
a command to use the handle of stream 3.

Rename source file extension to `.bak` for easy testing.
Change back to `del` the file if so desire.

Use `enabledelayedexpansion` to avoid echo of string
with poison characters to avoid errors.

Fixed known errors, not actual encryption etc. as the
later can be your research and development to do.

Updated with delayed expansion at top of script
to allow many variables to use delayed expansion.

---

Result displays encrypt and decrypt abnormalities (with no errors).

To encrypt:

```
"797816-901A5E25AE3F84AAC67979FF01AA681E"|Mon, 29 Feb 2016 11:54:54 GMT|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
```

Decrypted:

```
"7k7d16-k01a5e25ae3fd4aac67k7kff01aa6d1e"4mon, 2k feb 2016 11:54:54 gmt4application/vndropenxmlformats-officedocumentrpresentationmlrpresentation4application/vndropenxmlformats-officedocumentrpresentationmlrpresentation
```

Comment: you are a saint. Thank you so much for spending the time to help me. Unfortunately there is still a snag. I have redone my question to include your code and a new error log of the issue.

Comment: Hello @michael_heath, it appears that your solution still does not handle a few poison characters. Thank you for your help in improving my code though. Any further advice you could give on my current error with your improvements added would be really appreciated.

Comment: This solution does not handle "%! but when enabled delayed expansion is extended to the entire encryption decryption section it is able to handle " but not %!.

Comment: I have no full solution or a new version ready to post. Single characters without double quotes may need to be escaped by a `^`. i.e. `if ^%a:~,1% == ^%b:~,1%`. This does not handle `%` which needs to be escaped like `%%`, which is 2 characters, though can be 1 as a stored value and 0 if the variable is expanded and thus removed when evaluated. What is fixed in one part of the code, breaks another part. Error free execution may end up with output that is not correct. I have not tried full delayed expansion yet. Perhaps possible to solve, though I have doubt that this language can do this task.

Comment: Updated answer. Seems close so that perhaps you can check the encrypt and decrypt operation and see if it can recover the original text from encrypted text.